# Can a generic version of a derived class override a base method using the generic type?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, generics, clr

Consider:

```
Public MustInherit Class Column
    Public ReadOnly Property ReturnSomethingUseful() As Object
        Get
             'return something useful
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class TypedColumn(Of T)
    Inherits Column

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ReturnSomethingUseful() As T
        Get
             'return the same something useful, but as type T
             Return MyBase.ReturnSomethingUseful()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

But this gives the following error:

> Public Overrides Function ReturnSomethingUseful(sValue As String) As Boolean' 
>       cannot override 'Public Overridable Function ReturnSomethingUseful(sValue As String) As Object'
>       because they differ by their return types.

I accept that you can't do this, but I'd like to be able to preserve the semantics of what I'm **trying** to do, which is to have an untyped version that deals with `Object`, but a typed version in derived classes that knows about the specific type `T`.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't love this answer, but here's what I'm doing until I can find a truly elegant solution to this problem:

```
Public Class TypedColumn(Of T)
    Inherits Column

    Public ReadOnly Property ReturnSomethingUsefulTyped() As T
        Get
          'return the same something useful, but as type T
          Return MyBase.ReturnSomethingUseful()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

So instead of overriding the base method, it's just got a different name that indicates what it does.  Not wonderful, but better than dealing with type `Object` and also better than the problems with `Shadows`.

Comment: Yeah, I hate this too, but it was the only way I could manage it. In my case I was simply casting `ReturnSomethingUseful` to the type I required.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is: Use the [`Shadows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) modifier

```
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property ReturnSomethingUseful() As T
    Get
         'return the same something useful, but as type T
         Return MyBase.ReturnSomethingUseful()
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Shadows doesn't have quite the correct behavior: if I've got a variable of the base type (Column) and call the ReturnSomethingUseful method, then it calls the base class method and NOT the derived class method.  I'm not sure this is ever what you'd want, but in my situation it's completely wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: I know that this is the behavior of `Shadows`. But that is the only way to achieve a different return type in a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I got cut off from editing by the stupid 5 min limit thing ...

Anyway, I was going to say, it's a bit like the inability to do something like the following:

```
Private _myProperty As Integer = 0

ReadOnly Property MyProperty As String
    Get
        Return _myProperty.ToString("0,###")
    End Get
End Property

WriteOnly Property MyProperty As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)
        _myProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I think it's valid to be able to write a different type to a property than you read from it. Eg when managing UI date-times. Much cleaner to simply read the date-time as a formatted string than mess about in the UI code. I know I'll be in a minority here and the real coders will run screaming.

Comment: I think you can accomplish this cleanly by overriding CType to provide a conversion operator between the type of your object and the type you want to use instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-a-conversion-operator